# ARM template, Incorrect Segment Lengths during deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a bicep to deploy a static web app:

```
@description('rootCustomDomainName')
param rootCustomDomainName string = 'https://xyz.contoso.com'

resource staticWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'my-ui'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Free'
    tier: 'Free'
  }
  properties: {
    allowConfigFileUpdates: true
    branch: branch
    buildProperties: {
      appLocation: 'UI/web-app'
      skipGithubActionWorkflowGeneration: true
    }
    enterpriseGradeCdnStatus: 'Disabled'
    provider: 'DevOps'
    repositoryUrl: repositoryUrl
    stagingEnvironmentPolicy: 'Disabled'
  }
}

resource rootCustomDomain 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites/customDomains@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: staticWebApp
  name: rootCustomDomainName
  properties: {}
}
```

On deploying this, I see the following error:

> [error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource `my-ui/https://xyz.contoso.com` for type 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites/customDomains' at line '1' and column '2294' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name.

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried to reproduce in my environment and got below results.
- I have followed the template which you have provided.
- We need to pass only a custom domain name.
  Ex:`xyz.contoso.com` in the template but after that I got the below error.

[image]

***Modified bicep Template:***

```json
param staticWebApp string = '<staticWebAppName>'
param repositoryUrl string ='<Url>'
param DomainName string = 'CustomDomainName'

resource static_name_resource 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: staticWebApp
  location: 'WestUS2'
  sku:
{
name: 'Free'
    tier: 'Free'
  }
properties:
{
repositoryUrl: repositoryUrl
branch: 'main'
    stagingEnvironmentPolicy: 'Disabled'
    allowConfigFileUpdates: true
    provider: 'DevOps'
    enterpriseGradeCdnStatus: 'Disabled'
  }
}

resource static_DomainName 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites/customDomains@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: static_name_resource
  name: DomainName
  location: 'globel'
  properties:
{
}
}
```

- The static web app is deployed successfully but custom domain is not deployed.
- For that you need to attach the auto generated **URL** of **static web app** to custom domain in **DNS Zone** to verify auto generated **URL** of static web app and attach the custom domain as below.
- Search for **DNS Zone** and use the auto generated URL in Alias as below and click on **save**.

[image]

- After the above steps **redeploy** the static app once again as below.

[image]

- Now The Custom domain is added successfully to static web app.

[image]

- After that navigate to `static web app` -> `custom domain`.

[image]